# Making Form1 defined boolean accessible in class

Tags: class, boolean

in class Snake I Have:

```
public Snake()
{
  snakeRec = new Rectangle[3];

  if(Form1.diffeasy = true)
  {
    colorid = "Green";
  }
  else if (Form1.diffnormal = true) 
  {
    colorid = "blue";
  }
  else if (Form1.diffhard = true) 
  {
    colorid = "purple";
  }
  else if (Form1.diffextreme = true)
  {
    colorid = "red";
  }


  Sbrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromName(colorid)
```

Now the diffextreme, diffeasy,... are defined in Form1 as

```
bool diffeasy = false;
bool diffnormal = false;
bool diffhard = false;
bool diffextreme = false;
```

When a user chooses a difficulty, one of these is set to true.

My question is: How do I correctly access these booleans in the snake class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have `accessor methods` i.e. getter/setter methods defined in Form1 to access your fields of `Form1` e.g. for `diffeasy`:

```
   boolean isDiffeasy (){
       return this.diffeasy;
   }

   void setDiffeasy (boolean diffeasy){
       this.diffeasy = diffeasy ;
   }
```

Use this methods of `Form1` in `Snake` class as:

```
   if(form1.isDiffeasy()) {
       colorid = "Green";
    }

    ....
    form1.setDiffeasy (false);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to write the if syntax with boolean variable like this

```
if (value = true) // Incorrect Syntax
```

rather then you can right

```
if(value) // reason is if takes boolean variable.
```

Also you can write it improper way like this

```
if(value == true).
```

You can use setter and getter function to access and set the boolean operators.